# Can I execute the command for each result of the file globbing in zsh without for?

Tags: shell, foreach, zsh, glob

I am searching for away to execute the current command for each result of the file globbing  without building a for loop. I saw this somewhere but can't remember where exactly.

(The echo is just an example, it should also work with psql for example)

Example:

```
$ touch aaa bbb ccc ddd
$ echo "--- " [a-c]*
---  aaa bbb ccc
```

Desired output:

```
---  aaa
---  bbb
---  ccc
```

Kown way:

```
$ for i in [a-c]*; do echo "--- " $i ; done
---  aaa
---  bbb
---  ccc
```

Could be done using for. But maybe there is a way to do it shorter? Maybe like using double curly braces around the glob or whatever?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be looking for [`zargs`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zargs), a command with the same purpose as `xargs` but a saner interface.

```
autoload -U zargs
zargs -n 1 -- * -- mycommand
```

Answer (score 2):

The `printf` command will implicitly loop if given more arguments than placeholders in the format string:

```
printf -- "--- %s\n"  [a-c]*
```

To execute a command on each file, you need `xargs`: I assume you have GNU xargs that has the `-0` option:

```
printf "%s\0" [a-c]* | xargs -0 -I FILE echo aa FILE bb
```

Replace the `echo` xargs command with whatever you need, using the "FILE" placeholder where you need the filename.

Use your own judgement to determine if this is actually better or more maintainable than a for-loop.

Comment: Oh, nice one thanks. But actually the echo was just an example. The actual command I want to issue is "psql ... -f $i" :-)